# Codeigniter Doctrine is not working with underscore( _ ) class name

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine, codeigniter-2

Hello guys i created Entity folder inside application/model/. In Entity folder i created file Mj_user.php and give class name as same Mj_user.

but when i try to access that class using

```
$User= new Entity\Mj_user;
```

it's giving me error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Entity\Mj_user' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\controllers\user.php on line 15
```

what should i do Please help me..but when i remove Mj_ then put only file name as User.php. Its working properly..Please help me

Comment: Did you define model namespace?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new class you have to be careful, the name of the class must be:

```
class Mj_user extends CI_Model {
   function __contruct()
   {
        partent::construct();
   }
}
```

The file must be `mj_user.php` and for using this model you must load it before start using it
it can be preloaded for all in the configuration or you can load it whenever you need it like this

```
$this->load->view('mj_user');
```

And in the error seems that is looking for a file called user.php and should be mj_user.php